# DB2 dinamic search

Tags: db2

I need to create search (like '%-99' or like '%NON%')---there for all tables in SYS in DB2 in all columns --below code
---please for help--this is test code---but I have DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0206N  "WHERE" is not valid in the context where it is used.

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_DINAMIC_TEST_SEARCH
(
TABSET VARCHAR(128)
,   TABSCHEMA  VARCHAR(128)
,   TABNAME    VARCHAR(128)
,   COLUMN_NAME  VARCHAR(128)
,   ROW_COUNT   BIGINT
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED
;

```
BEGIN
FOR C AS CUR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_DINAMIC_TEST_SEARCH SELECT ''' 
    ||''' ,''' || TABLE_SCHEM || ''',''' || TABLE_NAME || ''',''' || COLUMN_NAME || ''', COUNT( DISTINCT(' || COLUMN_NAME || ')) FROM '
    || '"' ||  TABLE_SCHEM || '"."' || TABLE_NAME|| '"' ||WHERE|| '"' || COLUMN_NAME || '"' || LIKE || '"' ||'%-99'|| '"' || AS S
    FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = 'DWD' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_X_%'
    WITH UR
DO
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C.S;
      COMMIT;
END FOR;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong expression is used.
Try this:

```
SELECT 
   'INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_DINAMIC_TEST_SEARCH SELECT ''' 
|| ''' ,''' || TABLE_SCHEM || ''',''' || TABLE_NAME || ''',''' || COLUMN_NAME || ''', COUNT( DISTINCT(' || COLUMN_NAME || ')) FROM '
|| '"' ||  TABLE_SCHEM || '"."' || TABLE_NAME|| '" WHERE "' || COLUMN_NAME || '" LIKE ''%-99''' AS S
FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = 'DWD' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_X_%'
/*
AND 
(
   TYPE_NAME LIKE '%CHAR' 
OR TYPE_NAME LIKE '%GRAPHIC'
OR TYPE_NAME LIKE '%CLOB'
)
*/
WITH UR
```

BTW,
It's worth to generate the `INSERT SELECT` statements for string columns only as shown in the commented out lines.
Try not to use tables in the `SYSIBM` schema in `Db2 for LUW` - they are not documented and their content may be changed with some new release / fixpack without any notice. Use `SYSCAT` views instead - the `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` view in your case.

Comment: Thanks Mark. For info code work correct if I exclude where condition (where column_name like '%-99'), it gives count(distinct (columns)) from --loop table, but when I include where (where column_name like '%-99') it give errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your comment. Have you tried this amended (namely in the line you mentioned) statement, which I provided? What's the error / unexpected result you get now?

Comment: It seems that code work in first version 'WHERE ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' LIKE '%-99'', there is obvious errors with apostrophe and where I used in code. Thanks Mark for all your activities and help.